# Fast repetitions of Backspace key not accepted (but other keys are)

Tags: keyboard

If I doublestrike `Backspace`, it deletes only one character.
If I doublestrike 'a', I get 'aa'.

I initially only noticed the first case, and assumed this was just the "Character Repeat" setting in Windows, but I'm now convinced that the behaviour for `Backspace` is not matching the behaviour for everything else.

Can anyone advise how to fix this?

Comment: My only guess would be to go into Settings -> Ease of Access -> Turn off Filter Keys. If that setting is already off or doesn't change anything I'd try another keyboard.

Comment: Nope, already off :( Will try the keyboard